# To extract street number from street address using regex from a dataframe in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
d1 = dataset['End station'].head(20)

for x in d1:
    x = re.compile("[0-9]{5}")

print(d1)
```

Using  `dataset['End_Station'] = dataset['End station'].map(lambda x: re.compile("([0-9]{5})").search(x).group())`

shows - `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object.`
I am new to data analysis, can't think of any other methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Pandas* has its own methods concerning *Regex*, so the "more pandasonic" way
to write code is just to use them, instead of native *re* methods.

Consider such example of source data:

```
                      End station
0    4055 Johnson Street, Chicago
1  203 Mayflower Avenue, Columbus
```

To find the street No in the above addresses, run:

```
df['End station'].str.extract(r'(?P<StreetNo>\d{,5})')
```

and you will get:

```
      StreetNo
0     4055
1      203
```

Note also that the street No may be **shorter** than 5 digits, but you attempt
to match a sequence of just **5** digits.

Another weird point in your code: Why do you compile a regex in a loop
and then make no use of them?

## Edit

After a more thorough look at your code I have a couple of additional remarks.

When you write:

```
for x in df:
    ...
```

then the loop iterates actually over **column names** (not rows).

Another weird point in your code is that *x* variable, used initially to hold
a column name, you use again to save a compiled regex there.
It is a bad habbit. Variables should be used to hold one clearly
defined object in each of them.

And as far as iteration over rows is concerned, you can use e.g.

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    ...
```

But note that *iterrows* returns **pairs** composed of:

- index of the current row,
- the row itself.

Then (in the loop) you will probably refer to individual columns of this row.